# To simplify these sphinx query into 1

Tags: php, sphinx

I have 4 sphinx queries.
I want to make them in one.

1. `^mango$`
2. `^mango !(^mango$)`
3. `mango !(^mango$ | ^mango)`
4. `*mango* !(^mango$ | ^mango | mango)`

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can as such. some of the queries are the opposite of each other.

eg, 1. says only documents where mango is the only word in a field. 
but 2. says to exclude such documents.

and 4. will never match anything!

If you combined the queries with 'AND', then nothing would ever match.

If combined with 'OR' you end up with stuff cancelling out, ie, pretty much boils down to

```
^mango$ | ^mango | mango
```

which in turn becomes, simply

```
mango
```

---

Edit: So if you just trying to get 'better' matches to rise to the top, you could use a query of

```
mango | ^mango$ | ^mango | ^mango | mango$
```

which just requires mango anywhere, but items that more of the items should in general rank better.

But may need to play with the ranking mode, to get a good effect, the WORD-COUNT mode, is a good (if primitive start), can further extended it with the custom ranker.

Comment: Using SPH_RANK_SPH04 is a good start. But can also create a OR query with lots of different types, but it wouldnt be combining your example queries.